# Firebase Email/Password Authenticatiion Failed for new user Registered in android studio please check my java code below

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem in during testing Firebase Email/Password Authentication Failed for the new user registered please check my code and buil.gradle below and give me solutions. and I have tried much time but every time show failed issue happend. i have tried change many time Firebase dependencies with old and new version and not any changes and still i have problem please resolve my issue

Build.gradle

> java

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dubey.cabspyzo.pyzocabs.pyzo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Activity.Java

> Java

```
package dubey.cabspyzo.pyzocabs.pyzo;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class DriverLoginRegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button DriverLoginButton;
    private Button DriverRegisterButton;
    private TextView DriverRegisterLink;
    private TextView DriverStatus;
    private EditText EmailDriver;
    private EditText PasswordDriver;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;


    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_login_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        DriverLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.driver_login_btn);
        DriverRegisterButton =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.driver_register_btn);
        DriverRegisterLink =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.driver_register_link);
        DriverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.driver_status);
        EmailDriver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_driver);
        PasswordDriver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_driver);

        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);



        DriverRegisterButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        DriverRegisterButton.setEnabled(false);


        DriverRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                DriverLoginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                DriverRegisterLink.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                DriverStatus.setText("Register Driver");

                DriverRegisterButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                DriverRegisterButton.setEnabled(true);

            }
        });

         DriverRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view)
             {
                  String email = EmailDriver.getText().toString();
                  String password = PasswordDriver.getText().toString();

                  RegisterDriver(email, password);

             }
         });



    }




    private void RegisterDriver(String email, String password)
    {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
        {
            Toast.makeText(DriverLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Please Fill Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
        {
            Toast.makeText(DriverLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Please Fill Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else
        {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Driver Registration");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please Wait, While we are register your data...");
            loadingBar.show();

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                 .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)

                     {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(DriverLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Driver Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(DriverLoginRegisterActivity.this, "Registration Failed, Please try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                            }
                     }
                 });

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error?